# How do I use functional chaining with composition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, function-composition

I have this code that is building a url endpoint taking in different parameters:

```js
const query = (obj) => {
  let starter = 'query='
  let queryToString = JSON.stringify(obj)
  return `${starter}${queryToString}`
}

const params = (str) => `${str}`

const endpoint = (protocol, base, params, query) => {
  if (!params && !query) return `${base}`
  if (!params) return `${base}${query}`
  return `${protocol}${base}?${params}&${query}`
}

const baseUrl = 'api.content.io'

const protocol = (secure = true) => secure ? 'https://' : 'http://'

let result = endpoint(protocol(), baseUrl, params('limit=5&order=desc'),
  query({
    field: 'title',
    include: 'brands'
  }));

console.log(result)
```

This builds a string like:

```
https: //api.content.io?limit=5&order=desc&query={"field":"title","include":"brands"}
```

Is it possible to refactor this code such that the *conditionals inside the `endpoint` function can be removed*, the right concatenation strings be applied and the whole thing chained into a functional call like

```
Endpoint.chain(protocol(p)).chain(base(b)).chain(params(p)).chain(query(q)).build()
```

How do I get started with doing this?

UPDATE: The solutions below are pretty good but I would like to understand how functional programmers use ADTs (Algebraic Data Types) with Monads to solve this problem. The idea is to run a `chain` of functions and then a `fold` to get back the value I want

Comment: Are you sure you _want_ do something like this? `base` isn't really a parameter of `params`. None of these are subordinate to any other. They are all equal participants in making an endpoint. If you wish to show the names of the components in a call, the JS idiom is something like `endpoint({protocol, base, params, query})` called using the object shorthand notation.

Comment: hmm..you're right. Are you saying i should reach for functional composition only when the parameters match? This might be a mis-application?

Comment: @RayToal what I want to do actually is chain the function calls I guess - so that the endvalue of one function is passed into another and the necessity to check for null values is removed

Comment: You mean like this? `Endpoint.protocol(p).base(b).params(p).query(q).build()`

Comment: Yes!  - that's what I want - and i also want to remove the null and conditional checks and automatically concatenate with the correct separators

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

Chaining basically happens when you return the complete object in every function call. Here each function sets the value of its given chunk and returns the this object for whatever context it's attached to. Each function would be able to process the value it receives and the value function would build the url based on the set parameters.

```
var Endpoint = {
    protocol: protocol,
    base: base,
    params: params,
    query: query,
    value: value
}
function protocol(b) {
    protocol.value = b && 'https://' || 'http://';
    return this;
}
function base(s) {
    base.value = s || '';
    return this;
}
function params(s) {
    params.value = s || '';
    return this;
}
function query(s) {
    query.value = s || '';
    return this;
}
function value(s) {
    return   '$protocol$base$params$params$query'
        .replace('$protocol',protocol.value)
        .replace('$base',base.value)
        .replace('$params',params.value)
        .replace('$query',query.value)
}

Endpoint
    .protocol(true)
    .base('www.foo.com')
    .params('one/two/three')
    .query('?foo=bar')
    .value()
// "https://www.foo.comone/two/three$params?foo=bar"
```

Comment: This is very close but I would like to understand how functional programmers use ADTs (Algebraic Data Types) with Monads to solve this problem

Comment: I am a little confused as to how this code works. Could you tell me how `base.value = s || ''` actually works? I mean the left side. Where does `base` in `base.value` come from?

Comment: This is a decorator pattern implemented with method chaining. You are either brilliant or your syllabus is brilliantly written. Incredibly, and by accident, Monads are illustrated beautifully in this example. As far as the details you asked about, I'll give you a hint, functions are objects too!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a class for that, which has methods that allow chaining (they return `this`):

```js
class EndPoint {
    constructor() {
        // defaults
        this.prot = 'https://';
        this.bas = 'api.content.io';
        this.qry = '';
        this.par = '';
    }
    secure(on = true) {
        this.prot = on ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        return this;
    }
    base(str) {
        this.bas = str;
        return this;
    }
    query(obj) {
        this.qry = `query=${JSON.stringify(obj)}`
        return this;
    }
    params(str) {
        this.par = str
        return this;
    }
    build() {
        let sep1 = this.qry.length || this.par.length ? '?' : '';
        let sep2 = this.qry.length && this.par.length ? '&' : '';
        return `${this.prot}${this.bas}${sep1}${this.par}${sep2}${this.qry}`;
    }
};

let result = new EndPoint().secure(true).base('www.example.com')
    .params('limit=5&order=desc').query({ field: 'title', include: 'brands' }).build();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answers will work, but if you want the syntax to start with `Endpoint().` then use a class EndpointBuilder and a factory function like below.

```
class EndpointBuilder {

    constructor() {
        this.params = [];
        this.protocol = 'http://';
        this.baseUrl = 'api.endpoint.io';
    }

    base(url) {
        if (url && url.trim().length > 0)
            this.baseUrl = url;
        return this;
    }

    secure() {
        this.protocol = 'https://';
        return this;
    }

    setParam(param, val) {
        if (param && val)
            this.params.push({ param, val });
        return this
    }

    toString() {

        const url = `${this.protocol}${this.baseUrl}`;
        if (this.params.length <= 0)
            return url;

        let qString = '';
        this.params.forEach(p => {
            qString = `${qString}${qString.length > 0 ? '&' : ''}${p.param}=${JSON.stringify(p.val)}`;
        });

        return `${url}?${qString}`;
    }
};

// Endpoint Factory
const Endpoint = function () {
    return new EndpointBuilder();
};
```

**Usage Example:**

```
const url1 = Endpoint().setParam('limit', 5).setParam('query', { field: 'title', include: 'brands' }).toString();

const url2 = Endpoint().base('another.endpoint.io').setParam('limit', 5).setParam('order', 'desc').setParam('query', { field: 'title', include: 'brands' }).toString();

const url3 = Endpoint().base('another.endpoint.io').secure().setParam('limit', 5).setParam('order', 'desc').setParam('query', { field: 'title', include: 'brands' }).toString();

console.log(url1);   
// http://api.endpoint.io?limit=5&query={"field":"title","include":"brands"}

console.log(url2);
// http://another.endpoint.io?limit=5&order="desc"&query={"field":"title","include":"brands"}

console.log(url3);
// https://another.endpoint.io?limit=5&order="desc"&query={"field":"title","include":"brands"}
```